# give a key value to an np array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, hdf5

I have an array that is composed of multiple np arrays. I want to give every array a key and convert it to an HDF5 file

```
arr = np.concatenate((Hsp_data, Hsp_rdiff, PosC44_WKS, PosX_WKS, PosY_WKS, PosZ_WKS,
                     RMS_Acc_HSp, RMS_Acc_Rev, RMS_Schall, Rev_M, Rev_rdiff, X_rdiff, Z_I, Z_rdiff, time), axis=1)
d1 = np.random.random(size=(7501, 15))
hf = h5py.File('data.hdf5', 'w')
hf.create_dataset('arr', data=d1)
hf.close()
hf = h5py.File('data.hdf5', 'r+')
print(hf.key)
```

This what I have done so far and I get this error AttributeError: 'File' object has no attribute 'key'.

I want the final answer to be like this when printing the keys

```
<KeysViewHDF5 ['Hsp_M', 'Hsp_rdiff', 'PosC44_WKS', 'PosX_WKS', 'PosY_WKS', 'PosZ_WKS', 'RMS_Acc_HSp', 'RMS_Acc_Rev', 'RMS_Schall', 'Rev_M', 'Rev_rdiff', 'X_rdiff', 'Z_I', 'Z_rdiff']>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Where in the `h5py` docs did you find information about a `key` attribute?  Looks like you already know about `keys()`; why are you making up another?   What's with that `arr` array?  You aren't using it in the file creating.  What does `arr` look like.

Comment: I got the data from .mat file. This is from where I know about `keys()` but I had to make some transformations using numpy array so I lost the keys. I coudn't find any solutions to preserve them so I am trying to build the hole thing from scratch.
If you have any suggestions to modify  a .mat file it will be great!!

Comment: Is the .mat file the `h5py` compatible form or `scipy.io.loadmat`?  I'm familiar with the old `loadmat` format.  And have used `h5py`, but haven't explored MATLAB's use of that format much.

Comment: I tried that solution but no it is not compatible for matlab v7.3. So I guess it's the new version

Comment: There are multiple problems in your code. First, use `hf.keys()` to get root level HDF5 object names. In your case, it will only be the dataset named `arr`,  with the random data you added with `hf.create_dataset('arr', data=d1)`. If you want to create a dataset from `arr`, you need `hf.create_dataset('arr', data=arr)`. Warning: I don't think it's what you want. Concatenating all of your data into a 1 array will create 1 dataset. If you want 1 dataset for each name listed, you need to save them individually to different datasets,

Answer (score 0):

You/we need a clearer idea of how the original .mat is laid out. In h5py, the file is viewed as a nested set of groups, which are dict like. Hence the use of keys(). At the ends of that nesting are datasets which can be loaded (or saved from) as numpy arrays. The datasets/arrays don't have keys; it's the file and groups that have those.

Creating your file:

```
In [69]: import h5py
In [70]: d1 = np.random.random(size=(7501, 15))
    ...: hf = h5py.File('data.hdf5', 'w')
    ...: hf.create_dataset('arr', data=d1)
    ...: hf.close()
```

Reading it:

```
In [71]: hf = h5py.File('data.hdf5', 'r+')
In [72]: hf.keys()
Out[72]: <KeysViewHDF5 ['arr']>     
In [73]: hf['arr']
Out[73]: <HDF5 dataset "arr": shape (7501, 15), type "<f8">
In [75]: arr = hf['arr'][:]
In [76]: arr.shape
Out[76]: (7501, 15)
```

'arr' is the name of the dataset that we created at the start.  In this case there's no group; just the one dataset.  [75] loads the dataset to an array which I called `arr`, but that name could be anything (like the original `d1`).

Arrays and datasets may have a compound `dtype`, which has named `fields`.  I don't know if MATLAB uses those or not.

Without knowledge of the group and dataset layout in the original .mat, it's hard to help you.  And when looking at datasets, pay particular attention to `shape` and `dtype`.